# Azure Network Watcher | Connection troubleshoot -- NoRouteLearned

Tags: azure-virtual-network

### Not able to RDP to the azure vm from vm located in another vnet.
Vnet to vnet has site to site vpn connection and when i perform Network Watcher | Connection troubleshoot i can see that traffic is reaching from source vm ---> AzureFW-->-Source VPN GW---> Destination VPN GW---- then it point to destination vm ip as next hop and getting error message as listed below
Next hop IP address

### RTT from source (ms)

Issue
{"origin":"Local","severity":"Warning","type":"NoRouteLearned","context":[]}

Checked NSG  diag , IP Flow, Next hop and confirmed that it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are facing the issue above with [Connection Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-portal#check-connectivity-to-a-virtual-machine) feature of Azure Network Watcher and you have confirmed via NSG diag , IP Flow that you have set-up the connectivity correctly.

This is a known issue about the Connection Troubleshooting feature of Azure Network Watcher and the team is currently working on fixing this issue. You can use [Connection Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/connection-monitor-overview) instead to test this connectivity. Hope this helps!